# Android: Change to unsupported locale

Tags: android, locale

I been trying to change locale using the next code:

```
private void changeLocal(Locale locale){
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
          getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    refresh();
}

private void refresh() {
    finish();
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, getClass());
    startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

It works for French but not for Hebrew. So I looked in to device supported locales by calling `Locale.getAvailableLocales()` and I found out that French is there but Hebrew not.

If I put hardcoded Hebrew text I can see it, so it is installed, but I do not know how to force the device to use it.

Please help me force the device using Hebrew.

P.S
Wasn't been able to make this work without the `refresh` even when adding

```
android:configChanges="locale|layoutDirection"
```

to my Manifest it does not call the `onConfigurationChanged` of my Activity

Comment: Hebrew's locale is `iw`, not `he`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are 2 distinct standards, you have to double your values folder.

Add your Hebrew strings to these folders:

```
values-he
```

and

```
values-iw
```

Some devices will use one folder. Other devices will use the other one.

Note that **he** is actually `deprecated`. So, most devices will use **iw**